# Find number greater than given parameter in regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write whole line if city name and number of rooms greater than given parameter of function. so far, I have wrote following regex expression. But it finds only rooms available exactly given in parameter not more rooms.

```py
if re.search(r'R[0-9]{7},([-\w ]{1,30}%s[\w ]{1,30}),[0-9]{1,9},%d' % (city_name, number_of_bedrooms), string, re.IGNORECASE):
```

The file that I am looking into is:

```py
R2507956,2242 Grant Street Vancouver BC V5L 2Z7,1699000,5,2,House,13
R2500627,305-1006 Beach Avenue Vancouver BC V6E 1T7,981000,2,2,Condo,34
R2512107,680 W 6th Avenue Vancouver BC V5Z 1A3,989000,2,2,Townhouse,1
R2512000,208-607 E 8th Avenue Vancouver BC V5T 1T2,574900,1,1,Condo,1
R2511923,2146 W 14th Avenue Vancouver BC V6K 2V7,2248000,3,3,House,31
R2511301,2638 Charles Street Vancouver BC V5K 3A5,1890000,8,8,House,18
R2511809,307-2080 E Kent Avenue Vancouver BC V5P 4X2,449000,1,1,Condo,2
R2511747,1408-1775 Quebec Street Vancouver BC V5T 0E3,679900,1,1,Condo,5
R2511972,306-7180 Linden Avenue Burnaby BC V5E 3G6,448800,1,1,Condo,30
R2511059,7760 Berkley Street Burnaby BC V5E 2J7,1150000,2,1,House,20
R2511262,1106-9222 University Crescent Burnaby BC V5A 0A6,629800,2,2,Condo,4
R2510818,5190 Fulwell Street Burnaby BC V5G 1P2,1390000,7,4,House,15
R2510183,5712 Grant Street Burnaby BC V5B 2K4,1698000,3,4,House,18
R2512071,8154 Gilley Avenue Burnaby BC V5J 4Y5,2488000,9,9,House,1
R2510573,5059 Norfolk Street Burnaby BC V5G 1E9,1299000,4,4,House,7
R2512173,11226 236 Street Maple Ridge BC V2W 0C8 ,900000,4,4,House,35
R2512052,21560 Ashbury Court Maple Ridge BC V2X 8Z7,775000,3,2,House,43
R2508895,227-12258 224 Street Maple Ridge BC V2X 8Y7,474900,2,2,Condo,12
R2512451,102 Croteau Court Coquitlam BC V3K 6E2,948000,4,2,House,20
R2512494,1803-1185 The High Street Coquitlam BC V3B 0A9,968000,3,2,Condo,10
```

Comment: I wonder if a regex is the best tool here. You could split the lines and the do a regular filter on the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match and capture the number of bedrooms and then compare if a match occurred.

Also, you can match city names as whole words, that is where regex comes in handy.

Here is a snippet:

```py
number_of_bedrooms = 3
city_name = 'Vancouver'
rx = r'^R[0-9]{7},([^,]*\b%s\b[^,]*),\d{1,9},(\d+)' % (city_name)
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(rx, line, re.IGNORECASE)
        if m:
            if int(m.group(2)) >= number_of_bedrooms: # Nr of bedrooms is in Group 2
                print(line)
```

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/kM4QP8). Here, as `number_of_bedrooms = 3`, the output is

```py
R2507956,2242 Grant Street Vancouver BC V5L 2Z7,1699000,5,2,House,13
R2511923,2146 W 14th Avenue Vancouver BC V6K 2V7,2248000,3,3,House,31
R2511301,2638 Charles Street Vancouver BC V5K 3A5,1890000,8,8,House,18
```

Since the field with a city is withing commas, `[\w ]{1,30}` can be replaced with `[^,]*` patterns.

Comment: Can you please explain m.group(2). My teacher haven't told us about it, Thank you

Comment: @DalvirSingh The regex contains two groups, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i15GjQ/1). You form them with a pair of unescaped parentheses. To get the value of the first group, we use `m.group(1)`. To get the second, use `m.group(2)`. Read more [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: I got it now. Thank You for explanation. Really appreciate.